# Go to a specific item in card carousel

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

got a problem with getting the specific item to show when the page is loaded if link has some elements in it, I got it for one element but the else statement doesn't work, is it even possible to do it like this, sorry, Im new to js so Im just brainstorming
`    jQuery(function($){

```
let strings = ['?three#ecoedgebracket', 
'?three#ecoedgecornerhook'
];

strings.forEach( (string) => {

 if (string = '?three#ecoedgecornerhook') {
  jQuery('[data-showme]', function() {
    jQuery('.all-content3').hide();
    jQuery('#ecoedgecornerhook').show();
})} 


})})});
```

`

I tried also while, switch and for loops it doesnt work

Comment: You don't have an "else" condition here. Can you better explain in your question what it is you are trying to do? By "page is loading if link has some elements in it", do you mean there is a search parameter or hash parameter in the URL?

Your condition is also not using correct syntax, to check equality of values you need to use `==` or better `===`, so in your case: `string === '?three#ecoedgecornerhook'`.

Comment: Well I'm trying to show specific product with id as it says #ecoedgebracket or #ecoedgecornerhook, when on the other page the link is clicked, and I've tried else condition and the code doesnt work, also I have the similiar code for the tab and it works